# Add a count to simple JS to stop it repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a simple count to the below JavaScript in the hope it will only be performed once, ideally even on page refresh, but the form could be reloaded with ajax:

```js
jQuery(document).on('gform_post_render', function () {
    if (jQuery("#input_51_1").val().length > 0) {
        jQuery('form#gform_51').trigger('submit');
    } else {
        // Do nothing
    }
});
```

Comment: You could use the jquery.one() function: https://api.jquery.com/one/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) as a flag variable

First check if item in localStorage is setted with [getItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/getItem), and if is not set it using [setItem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)

```js
jQuery(document).on('gform_post_render', function () {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('gform_post_renderEventTriggered')) {
        localStorage.setItem('gform_post_renderEventTriggered', true);
        if (jQuery("#input_51_1").val().length > 0) {
            jQuery('form#gform_51').trigger('submit');
        } else {
            // Do nothing
        }
    } else {
        console.log("Already triggered");
    }
});
```

Comment: This doesn’t seem to fire anymore, could there be an error?

Comment: @EReport you need to think when to set gform_post_renderEventTriggered to false so you can allow the event `gform_post_render` to be triggered again

Comment: @EReport or may be use a [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)